# Multiplying Taylor series for $e^x$ with terms from converging sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}.$

For which $x \in \Bbb{R}$ does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k x^k}{k!}$ converge?

Here is my attempt:

Let $\epsilon =1.$ Then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ st $\forall n\geq N, |a_n -a| < 1$. Also $a_n < 1 +a.$

Then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k x^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{a_k x^k}{k!}+ \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{a_k x^k}{k!}.$ The first sum is finite (say it equals Y) so $ \leq Y +   \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{(a+1) x^k}{k!} \leq Y + (a+1)\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}  \frac{x^k}{k!}.$ This is the serie for $e^x$ but minus first $N-1$ terms so it must converge. Then multiplying by $(a+1)$ will still make it converge so $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k x^k}{k!}$ must converge for all R.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.

Comment: I would test for *absolute* convergence: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_k||x|^k}{k!}$ just to avoid the issues where the boundedness of the partial sums of the series does not imply convergence (in case they are not monotone); with a series with non-negative terms, monotonicity of partial sums is granted. Otherwise, the proof is ok.

Comment: Could also simplify: $(a_n)$ converges $\implies (|a_n|)$ converges $\implies (|a_n|)$ bounded. If $|a_n|\le M$ then $\frac{|a_n||x|^n}{n!}\le M\frac{|x|^n}{n!}$ and you can use comparison test directly (with Taylor series for $e^{|x|}$).

Comment: @StinkingBishop  I know this isn't part of the post but further down the text it says $e^{-x} f(x) -a = e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_k - a)x^k}{k!}$ but I don't understand why this is the case. If you see why this is can you explain? The text doesn't say much on this equality so perhaps this is really obvious.

Comment: $e^{-x}f(x)-a=e^{-x}(f(x)-ae^x)=e^{-x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_kx^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{ax^k}{k!}\right)=e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a_k-a)x^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the ratio test:

We need:

$\lim_\limits{k\to\infty}\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k} \frac {x^{k+1}}{x^k} \frac {k!}{(k+1)!} < 1$

Simplifying:

$\lim_\limits{k\to\infty}\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k} \frac {x}{k+1} < 1$

Since $a_k$ is convergent $\lim_\limits{k\to\infty}\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k} = 1$

$\lim_\limits{k\to\infty}\frac {x}{k+1} < 1$

The series will converge for all $x.$